# Missing files while storing several numpy arrays as jpg images python

Tags: python, image

> *The issue was just the **indentation** finally. – [**Jose Ramon**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194864/jose-ramon) [just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001724/storing-numpy-arrays-as-jpg-images-python#comment87020383_50001850)*

I am performing some processing in 2D numpy matrices (which correspond to audio signal spectrograms) and in the end I want to store them as images. In the end I have a list called splits contained 6 different 2D numpy matrices and I want in a for loop to store them with different names:

```
counter = 0
for item in splits:
    counter = counter + 1
    print counter
    pic_name = "path/" + str(counter) +"_.jpg"
    matplotlib.image.imsave(pic_name, item)
```

the `len(splits)` is 6 and the for loop run 6 times (in the print I got 1, 2, ..., 6). However, in the end **the only stored** image is **`6_.jpg`**, it seems that I am not storing the other ones just the last one. What am I missing here?

---

[A **live-MCVE** demonstrator code:](https://tio.run/##jY9LC8IwEITv/RVDLrYYqq2PQ7GCRxFF1HsJbdWITUKaIlL87TX11at7Gnbmm2XV3ZylCJtmu1tuDsl6sV8hBtnIG@owekBXokQqK2FyjThGPbRLJjIoLbMqza3gaSJYkbdurw6iR484PwBD5yg1uMkLcAE3oCEd0TGd0KkXObDTRb@qj@DldMUgipnzgFirNNr9BD30SeJf1Im845oLg@4N3x4umHG/vfRXSEFmVynVnMBz3lg7/6IF46JFm@YJ)

```
PRINT_MASK = "Now {2:} runs counter == {0:} and produced pic_name == '{1:}'"
counter = 0
for item in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
    counter = counter + 1
    pic_name = "path/" + str(counter) +"_.jpg"
    print PRINT_MASK.format( counter, pic_name, "<loop>" )
print     PRINT_MASK.format( counter, pic_name, "<main>" )
```

Yields:

```
Now <loop> runs counter == 1 and produced pic_name == 'path/1_.jpg'
Now <loop> runs counter == 2 and produced pic_name == 'path/2_.jpg'
Now <loop> runs counter == 3 and produced pic_name == 'path/3_.jpg'
Now <loop> runs counter == 4 and produced pic_name == 'path/4_.jpg'
Now <loop> runs counter == 5 and produced pic_name == 'path/5_.jpg'
Now <loop> runs counter == 6 and produced pic_name == 'path/6_.jpg'
Now <main> runs counter == 6 and produced pic_name == 'path/6_.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `opencv`.

```
import cv2
...
cv2.imwrite(pic_name,item)
```

Comment: The problem is that those matrices are correspond to spectograms so the matplotlib.image.imsave(pic_name, item) convert them to RGB instead of storing them as grayscale.

Comment: so you can convert the image to RGB:
`itemtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(item,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`.
BTW - if you use `cv2.imread` afterwards to load the image, it will read it in RGB by default.

Comment: The issue was just the indentation finally.